# How to select entire row in RecycleView using Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, recyclerview-layout

I’m fairly new in python but a complete beginner with Kivy. I find the documentation around Kivy to be hard to interpret at least for me. So far I have been able to create a RecycleView where I am able to add, remove and change data. Ideally, I want to be able to have as many columns as I want but all the data on each row belongs together. Hence if I select one I want to highlight all items on that row. I have tried with togglebutton but without any success. I simply don’t know how I can access each individual togglebutton in the RecycleView through ids or some other method. If I could access each togglebutton individually I could simply change its state to be equal to ‘Down’. So far I have only been able to find which row the user selected (however not so elegantly). I managed this by calculating the number of buttons per row and comparing this against the index of the selected button.

Here is an example where I'm experimenting, usually I prefer using the .kv file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior


class MyButton(RecycleDataViewBehavior, ToggleButton):
    index = None

    def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):
        """ Catch and handle the view changes """
        self.index = index
        return super(MyButton, self).refresh_view_attrs(
            rv, index, data)


class TestRecycleView(RecycleView):
    items_per_row = 3
    selected_data = None
    selected_row = None

    def find_row(self, instance):
        self.selected_row = instance.index // self.items_per_row + 1
        print('Row: ', self.selected_row)
        self.selected_data = self.data[(self.selected_row - 1) * self.items_per_row: self.items_per_row
                                       * self.selected_row]
        print('Data: ', self.selected_data)


KV = '''

<MyButton>:
    on_release:
        app.root.find_row(self)

TestRecycleView:
    data: [{'text': str(x)} for x in range(21)]
    viewclass: 'MyButton'
    id: rv_controller
    target_id: None
    RecycleGridLayout:
        cols: 3
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        orientation: 'vertical'
        key_selection: 'selectable'
        default_size: None, dp(26)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        multiselect: True
        touch_multiselect: True

'''


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        # root.data = items
        return root


Test().run()
```

Since I have been able to calculate what row got selected by the user I can also calculate what data in the RecycleView that is being selected. However, I would like a neat visual representation for this kind of row selection.

Would greatly appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hack to your `find_row()` method to set the state of all the buttons in a row. This method sets them to agree with the state of the `Button` instance selected, so you can also unselect.

```
def find_row(self, instance):
    rgl = self.ids.gl
    num_buttons = len(rgl.children)
    num_rows = num_buttons // self.items_per_row
    self.selected_row = instance.index // self.items_per_row + 1
    print('Row: ', self.selected_row)
    self.selected_data = self.data[(self.selected_row - 1) * self.items_per_row: self.items_per_row
                                   * self.selected_row]
    print('Data: ', self.selected_data)
    index1 = (num_rows - self.selected_row + 1) * self.items_per_row - 1
    index2 = index1 - self.items_per_row
    state = instance.state
    for index in range(index1, index2, -1):
        rgl.children[index].state = state
```

This also requires setting the id of the `RecycleGridLayout` as:

```
id: gl
```

The `Buttons` are children of the `RecycleGridLayout`, so that can be used to get the total number of `Buttons`. And the index into the `children` list is the opposite of what you would expect. That is that the `Button` labelled `0` is index `20` and the `Button` labelled `20` is index `0`. So the calculation of `index1` uses that knowledge to determine the index of the left-most `Button` in the selected row. Then the right-most `Button` in the selected row will be `index - 2`. The `range(inde1, index2, -1)` steps through the `Buttons` in the selected row. Since `find_row()` is called `on_release`, the `state` of the `instance` is already toggled, so its `state` can be used to set the `state` of the other `Buttons` in the row.

Comment: Finally! I have been searching for a solution for way to long. Do you mind writing a short summary of why this works. Seems like the .children method is the key here.

Comment: Hi again, the suggested solution worked great until I started updating the recycleview. If I change any data and would like to update the entire recycleview, I use these methods: root = App.get_running_app().root and root.refresh_from_data(). However the refresh_from_data() seems to switch the indices of the togglebutton. Index 0 toggles from being in the top left corner to the bottom right. This creates a weird behavior were clicking row 2 will toggle between selecting row 2 and row 2 from the bottom up. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think the "recycling" is causing this effect. When the `refresh_from_data()` happens, the `MyButton` instances are recycled, so that the label `0` is likely on a different instance of `MyButton` after the refresh. But the `state` of the recycled instances is not modified, so different buttons appear selected. You can add `'state': 'normal'` to each element of your `data`, then every refresh will restore the `normal` state to every button. If you want to maintain the `down` state of selected buttons, you will have to keep track of the selected buttons and reset their state after each refresh.

Comment: Yes this was my idea too, but I’m accessing each button through its index which keeps changing. This means every other refresh I have to keep track om how the indicies have been mirrored over the middle row. Lets say I press the first row. Then I add some data and want to refresh. Now I have to keep track on the fact that the first row now has the last rows index. This really seem like bugg to me. Why would anyone want the recycling to behave this way? Can I circumvent all this by accessing each button through an unique id or something? Again, thanks for being engaged with me!